# SQL for each data change where clause value through condition

Tags: sql

I have this function where i count data from db.

e.g

```
Select column1, count(), column2 
from table1 
left join table 2 and so on
where --- some statement
and (table1.date - table2.date) <= 2
group by column1, column2
```

Now what I need is to do something like this on my where clause for each data I would check, if table2 has a status 1 my where clause would be where status = 1 but if it doesnt, where status = 2

it is because what i needed is if there is a status of 1 in my table2 thats the data i would use in my table2.date, if it doesnt i would use status 2's data as  table2.date

Comment: Your query has no mention of `status` at all, so the logic is rather hard to follow.

Answer (score 1):

> if table2 has a status 1 my where clause would be where status = 1 but if it doesnt, where status = 2

To me this would translate as the following conditions in thee `WHERE` clause of your query:

```
(table2.status = 1 AND table1.status = 1) OR table1.status = 2
```

Comment: i have and additional 
((select count from table2 where table2.id = table1.id and table2.status =1) AND table1.status = 1) OR table1.status = 2 is this also correct?

Comment: @kev_m: I was just translating your English into SQL. Now if you want a fully working query, you would need to show us your entire current SQL query first...

Comment: the only thing i want here is if there is a count where status = 1 and table1.id is equal to table2.status set status = 1 or else set to status 2

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no `NULL` values in the `status` columns, the logic you want is:

```
where (table2.status = 1 and table1.status = 1) or
      (table2.status <> 1 and table1.status = 2)
```